# AutoEllipsis=true affects the vertical positioning of the text

Tags: c#, winforms, label, text-alignment

I have a label with `AutoEllipsis = true` and `TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft`. When I enter a text that is not extending the label width, the text is vertically aligned to the middle of the label.

[image]

However, when the text extends the label width the text is not aligned to the middle, but top aligned instead.

[image]

Why is it behaving this way, and is there a way to keep the text vertically center aligned?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I see it.  This looks like a limitation in the underlying winapi, [DrawTextEx()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Which doesn't get a lot of help from the Label class, it doesn't turn on the DT_SINGLELINE option (aka TextFormatFlags.SingleLine) since it is capable of rendering multiple lines.  DrawTextEx() documents that this is required to get vertically centered text (DT_VCENTER).  So the real bug is that it shouldn't be centered at all :)  Do note that you *do* get centered text when you grow the label vertically.

The simplest way to work around it is by setting the label's UseCompatibleTextRendering property to True.

Comment: Are there any obvious negative side effects to setting UseCompatibleTextRendering to true?

Comment: Depends on font, size and monitor resolution.  If you can't see it then it is not obvious.

Comment: I see according to documentation it changes the renderer from TextRenderer to Graphics. So it will be less precise. But for general use should be fine. Thanks...       https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.label.usecompatibletextrendering?view=windowsdesktop-6.0

Answer (score 0):

What I have done is set the top and bottom of the margin property to 3 and it worked well.
So have your margin be (3,3,3,3)!

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is by implementing a custom control that overrides the `OnPaint` method and does not call the base method.

```cs
public class LabelEx : Label {
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
        var flags = TextFormatFlags.SingleLine | TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter | TextFormatFlags.WordEllipsis;
        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, Text, Font, ClientRectangle, ForeColor, flags);
    }
}
```

One catch is that added event handlers will be ignored. (as a result of omitting the call to the base method)

Taken from [here](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?825759-RESOLVED-Label-Autoellipsis-text-moves-up&viewfull=1#post5026701).