# Text of label moves a few pixels when ellipsis added

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a label with `AutoSize = false` and `AutoEllipsis = true` and I noticed that in case when ellipsis added to the text of this label it moves a few pixels like in the following screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Why? What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [AutoEllipsis=true affects the vertical positioning of the text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24447344/autoellipsis-true-affects-the-vertical-positioning-of-the-text)

Comment: You are not doings anything wrong, it is a bug. In contrast to the answer in the duplicate, the best solution is to write your own autoellispis code. Some projects are out there but all rather complicated..

Comment: Do you know if there is a bug reported with MS for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24447344/autoellipsis-true-affects-the-vertical-positioning-of-the-text).

Whenever the text is too large it aligns to the Top, with (2) or without (1) `AutoEllipsis` on.

[image]

Unfortunately the proposed solution often looks rather ugly.

To workaround (3) you can either use a simple function like the one below or write a `Label` subclass that integrates the functionality.. :

```
string ReducedText(Label lbl, string text)
{
    char ell = (char)0x00002026;

    lbl.Tag = text;
    string redString = text;
    using (Font font = new Font(lbl.Font, FontStyle.Bold))
    using (Graphics G = lbl.CreateGraphics())
    {
        G.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
        float elltWidth = TextRenderer.MeasureText(G, ell.ToString(), font).Width;
        float textWidth = TextRenderer.MeasureText(G, redString, font).Width;
        elltWidth += lbl.Padding.Left + lbl.Padding.Right ;
        if (textWidth < lbl.ClientSize.Width) return text;  // maybe watch padding!
        SizeF s = SizeF.Empty;
        do
        {
            redString = redString.Substring(0, redString.Length - 1);
            s = TextRenderer.MeasureText(G, redString, font);
            // Console.WriteLine(s.Width + "  " + lbl.ClientSize.Width + " " + redString);
        } while (s.Width + elltWidth > lbl.ClientSize.Width);
    }
    return redString + ell;
}
```

On some bold fonts the ellipsis character looks like an underscore; in that case simply replace it with a string with 2-3 dots..!

Comment: Unfortunately your solution doesn't seem to work in my case -- text in the label still aligns. I use it like this -- `this.label.Text = ReducedText(this.label, str);`

Comment: Hm, the usage is as intended. Assuming that the TextAlignment is MiddleLeft you may need to increase the slack (3) I had to add a little; try 5-8..

Comment: Ok. Can you explain the Label a little: What are the images shown there?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73834/discussion-between-taw-and-frozenheart).

Comment: It's a simple Label with the following settings -- http://i.imgur.com/DtJEw6c.png, http://i.imgur.com/Rz01tTf.png

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to work around it is by setting the label's UseCompatibleTextRendering property to True.

Comment: It gives me the strange font

Answer (score 0):

Setting the top and bottom of the label's margin property to 3 seemed to do it for me. So set you margin to (3,3,3,3)!